# C# Regex syntax help for parsing string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this

```
var regex = new Regex(@"StartDate:(.*)EndDate:(.*)W.*Status:(.*)");
```

So this gets me values until it hits a W in the string correct? - I need it to stop at a W OR S. I have tried a few different ways but I am not getting it to work. Anyone got some info?

More info:

```
            record = record.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("-", "/");
            var regex = new Regex(@"StartDate:(.*)EndDate:(.*)W.*Status:(.*)");
            string strStartDate = regex.Match(record).Groups[1].ToString();
            string strEndDate = regex.Match(record).Groups[2].ToString();
            string Status = regex.Match(record).Groups[3].ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith("In") ? "Inactive" : "Active";
```

I am trying to parse a big string of values, I only want 3 things - Start Date, End Date, and Status (active/inactive). However there are 3 different values for each (3 start dates, 3 end dates, 3 status')

First 2 string go like this

```
"Start Date: 

 2014-09-08 



End Date: 

 2017-09-07 



Warranty Type: 

 XXX 



Status: 

 Active 



Serial Number/IMEI: 

 XXXXXXXXXXX









Description:



XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

The 3rd string is like this

```
"Start Date: 

 2014-09-08 



End Date: 

 2017-09-07 



Status: 

 Active 



Warranty Upgrade Code:



SVC_PRIORITY"
```

On the last string it will not display the dates because of the `W.*` after end date im guessing

**I am not getting the 2 dates on the last string**

Comment: What is/are the input string(s)?

Comment: updated my original post @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: if you need it to end at W or S then you'd do something like (.*)[WS]

Comment: @BugFinder I am not getting the dates if I do it like this: var regex = new Regex(@"StartDate:(.*)EndDate:(.*)[WS]Status:(.*)");

Comment: @Havoux Are you missing a `.*` between the `[WS]` and `Status`?

Comment: Looks like you need W or the start of Status.

Comment: @juharr oh! I added it and the results are same as my original syntax. I am getting the dates from the first 2 strings but no dates from the last one :/

Comment: Why not split with newlines first, and then split with `:`+space?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry can you show me what you mean? I dont follow

Comment: `var res = s.Split('\r', '\n').Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).Select(m => m.Split(new[] {": "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToDictionary(n => n[0], n => n[1]);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does doing this do exactly? or what would it allow me to do. I am not sure where to put this in my code?

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/jjEnX7).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh I see that is interesting. I am getting an error at n[1]) on .ToDictionary -- It says that " Index was outside the bounds of the array." I am pretty new to programming so I dont really know much terms or lingo yet

Comment: That means there can be no data, right? What is the string you test against? Did you use **`StringSplitOptions.None`**? Use it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my strings to show you in more detail exactly what I am trying to parse - I only want the 2 dates and status

Comment: I have added a pre-processing line of  code (`Regex.Replace`) that removes all newlines and excessive whitespace after `:`.

Comment: @juharr I do need W or the start of Status - I received a lot of answers but honestly I think they are overcomplicated. All I am looking for is to stop at W for Warranty type or S for Status - however I want to also get the value for status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Please try the function to parse using regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private static List<string[]> parseString(string input)
{
    var pattern = @"Start\s+Date:\s+([0-9-]+)\s+End\s+Date:\s+([0-9-]+)\s+(?:Warranty\s+Type:\s+\w+\s+)?Status:\s+(\w+)\s*";
    return Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().ToList().ConvertAll(m => new string[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value });

}

// To show the result string
var result1 = parseString(str1);
string result_string = string.Join("\n", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("Start Date: {0}\nEnd Date: {1}\nStatus: {2}", r)).ToArray());
MessageBox.Show(result_string);
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT2** For OP's situation, you could call the function from inside the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row Borderfluid")
    {
        string record = el.InnerText;
        //if record is the string to parse
        var result = parseString(record);
        var result_string = string.Join("\n", result.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("Start Date: {0}\nEnd Date: {1}\nStatus: {2}", r)).ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show(result_string);
    }
}
```

Comment: it wont let me MessageBox.Show(result) - cannot convert List.<<string>> to string is the error. Is there any other way to display the results other than MsgBox.Show

Comment: Once you've got List<string[]> as result, you could do what you like with it: Join them as string; use Messagebox.Show() to display it; or Console.WriteLine() to output to your console; or further process the data. To use MessageBox.Show(), you have to convert the result to a string. Did you do that?

Comment: I am not sure I can use a function in my situation due to this code is within a foreach loop - would it still be alright?

Comment: If you prefer not to use a function, just take the code inside { }. Remember to replace the `input` variable with your string variable, and assign the result to another variable. It should be alright

Comment: foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row Borderfluid")
                {
                    string record = el.InnerText;} -- This is what im putting the code inside, I am not sure if I can add a function within this? I just want the values of those items

Comment: That works! - Could you teach me how I could get all those values seperately though? i.e. 2014/09/08, 2017/09/07, Active. My next step is to input these values in a database table

Comment: In the function, `m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value` correspond to `Start Date`, `End Date` and `Status`. You can make modifications there. By 2014/09/08, 2017/09/07, do you mean to get all the start dates in a list?

Comment: I want to get all these start dates (3) end dates (3) and status (3) into a datatable row. The reason why i want it in a datatable is because I want to compare it with values from a different datatable

Comment: Take the 3rd string for example, the function returns such a list as result: {['2014-09-08', '2017-09-07','Active']}, then start date would be result[0][0], end date is result[0][1], so on. As to how to save them into database, that's off the topic.

Answer (score 1):

No need to replace the new lines in your example

```
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

var subjectString = @"Start Date: xxxxx
End Date: yyyy
Warranty Type: zzzz
Status: uuuu
Start Date: aaaa
End Date: bbbb
Status: cccc";

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"Start Date: (.*?)\nEnd Date: (.*?)\n(.|\n)*?Status: (.*)");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[2].Value);
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[4].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Is resultList an array ? should I create an ArrayList ?

Comment: You can make it a List or something else that supports the Add. My assumption here is that the subject string can contain multiple occurrences of the thing you want to match. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace your code with the following one ([see IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/7hvamK)):

```
var s = @"Start Date: xxxxx
End Date: xxxx
Warranty Type: xxxx
Status: xxxx";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @":\s+", ": ")            // Remove excessive whitespace
        .Split(new[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // Split each line with `:`+space
        .ToDictionary(n => n[0], n => n[1]);              // Create a dictionary
string strStartDate = string.Empty;
string strEndDate = string.Empty;
string Status = string.Empty;
string Warranty = string.Empty;
// Demo & variable assignment
if (res.ContainsKey("Start Date")) {
    Console.WriteLine(res["Start Date"]);
    strStartDate = res["Start Date"];
}
if (res.ContainsKey("Warranty Type")) {
    Console.WriteLine(res["Warranty Type"]);
    Warranty = res["Warranty Type"];
}
if (res.ContainsKey("End Date")) {
    Console.WriteLine(res["End Date"]);
    strEndDate = res["End Date"];
}
if (res.ContainsKey("Status")) {
    Console.WriteLine(res["Status"]);
    string Status = res["Status"];
}
```

Note that the best approach is to declare your own class with the fields like `WarrantyType`, `StartDate`, etc. and initialize that right in the LINQ code.

Comment: hmm why is it important to declare the classes? - My next step with this is to convert the dates to DateTime and input them into a database table - Would this be helpful for that next step?

Comment: No, it is not important, but it could be useful. It is up to you what you do with this further. Also, you can `.Trim()` the values when assigning to the variables. E.g. `Status = res["Status"].Trim()` (since the trailing whitespace is still there).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `.*` its a catch all which gets regex pattern creators in trouble. Instead create the pattern to match to a **specific** pattern in the data which always *occurs* in the data.

Your pattern are the two dates of `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d` the rest is anchor text, which should be used as static anchors which can be skipped.

Here is an example where it looks for the date patterns. Once found regex puts it into named match capture groups `(?<GroupNameHere>...)` and Linq extracts each match into a dynamic entity and parses the date times.

**Data**

*Note the first date is reversed as per your example*

```
var data = @"Start Date:

 2014-09-08

End Date:

 2017-09-07

Status:

 Active

Start Date:

 2014-09-09

End Date:

 2017-09-10

Status:

 In-Active
 ";
```

**Pattern**

```
string pattern = @"
^Start\sDate:\s+                     # An anchor of start date that always starts at the BOL
(?<Start>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)         # actual start date pattern
\s+                                  # a lot of space including \r\n
^End\sDate:\s+                       # End date anchor and space
(?<End>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)           # pattern of the end date.
\s+                                  # Same pattern as above for Status
^Status:\s+
(?<Status>[^\s]+)
 ";
```

**Processing**

```
// Explicit hints to the parser to ingore any non specified matches ones outside the parenthesis(..)
// Multiline states ^ and $ are beginning and eol lines and not beginning and end of buffer.
// Ignore allows us to comment the pattern only; does not affect processing.
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture |
                             RegexOptions.Multiline       |
                             RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new
            {
                Status    = mt.Groups["Status"].Value,
                StartDate = DateTime.Parse(mt.Groups["Start"].Value),
                EndDate   = DateTime.Parse(mt.Groups["End"].Value)
            })
```

**Result**

[image]